# SwiftUI sheet being presented on other tabs: Is this expected behavior?

Tags: ios, swiftui

In my app, I'm displaying a .sheet conditionally on an `@AppStorage` value, which gets set via a deep link (universal link). The app has tabs, and the .sheet is part of tab 1. However, if the app is in the background and is on tab 2, and then opens and the @AppStorage value is set, the .sheet gets shown on tab 2. I've replicated this behavior below in a demo app:

```
@main
struct TabExampleApp: App {
    @AppStorage("example") var example: String?
    @AppStorage("count") var count: Int = 0
    @Environment(\.scenePhase) var scenePhase

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }.onChange(of: scenePhase) { newPhase in
            if newPhase == .active {
                count += 1
                if count >= 3 {
                    example = "test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of setting the target `@AppStorage` value via a deep link, I'm just setting it on the 3rd app launch.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var appNavigationState = AppNavigationState()

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $appNavigationState.selectedTab) {
            Tab1()
                .tag(ContentViewTab.tab1)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab1")
                }
            
            Tab2()
                .tag(ContentViewTab.tab2)
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab2")
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class AppNavigationState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedTab: ContentViewTab = .tab1
}

enum ContentViewTab {
    case tab1
    case tab2
}
```

```
struct Tab1: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appNavigationState: AppNavigationState
    @AppStorage("example") var example: String?

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tab 1")
            .sheet(item: $example) { example in
                SheetView()
                    .presentationDetents([.medium])
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct Tab2: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var appNavigationState: AppNavigationState

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tab 2")
    }
}
```

```
struct SheetView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("This is my sheet!")
    }
}
```

So, to conclude it's not obvious to me that a .sheet that's part of Tab 1 should display while Tab 2 is open. Is this expected behavior or is this a bug?